# Remove unnecessary slashes from path

Tags: php

```
$path = '/home/to//my///site';
```

I am trying to remove unnecessary forward slashes `/` from the path above

I am trying to get this results

```
/home/to/my/site
```

I've failed with `str_replace`, since i don't know the number of slashes.

Comment: Why bother> If they work so what is the point of removing them?

Comment: this is a file manager script, this path will be shown for script's users

Comment: Why have the double slashes in the first place

Comment: @Ed Heal The code above is just for test, And i am free in my requests since it does not hurt somebody else, Thanks

Comment: use the php native function `realpath('/home/to//my///site')`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Elegant solution

With `preg_replace` you can obtain this with a single line of code:

```
preg_replace('#/+#','/',$str);
```

The pattern `/+` will match the forwardslash `/` one or more times, and will replace it with a single `/`.

### Not-so Elegant solution

There are of course other ways to achieve this, for example using a `while` loop.

```
while( strpos($path, '//') !== false ) {
   $path = str_replace('//','/',$path);
}
```

This will call `str_replace` until all occurrences of `//` are replaced. You can also write that loop in a single line of code if you want to sacrifice readability (not suggested).

```
while( strpos( ($path=str_replace('//','/',$path)), '//' ) !== false );
```

Comment: i am not that good with Regex but why not `\/{2,}` and reduce the cycles for checking the single `/` which isnt necessary

Comment: If you want to use this for URLs, this regex is protocol safe:

`preg_replace('#(?<!:)/+#gm', '/', $str);`

Answer (score 13):

if someone wants to remove extra slashes from URL without removing first two slashes after http/https:

```
$url = preg_replace('/([^:])(\/{2,})/', '$1/', $url);
```

(thanks to ツ Liverbool
[how to remove multiple slashes in URI with 'PREG' or 'HTACCESS'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339145/how-to-remove-multiple-slashes-in-uri-with-preg-or-htaccess))

Answer (score 4):

Hello may this will helpful

Write this code in your .Htaccess file and check it..

```
# Prevent double slashes in URLs, e.g. //Blog and /Home//About
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the build-in function [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) for stripping slashes of existing files. But you will always end up with a canonicalized absolute pathname.

```
<?php
// 2 slashes
echo realpath('/etc//passwd') . PHP_EOL; // prints /etc/password
// 3 slashes
echo realpath('/etc///passwd') . PHP_EOL; // prints /etc/password
// 2 ..
echo realpath('/etc/../etc/passwd') . PHP_EOL; // prints /etc/password
?>
```

Please note that this function returns an error if the file **does not** exist.

Some important remarks from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to
>   '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path and returns
>   the canonicalized absolute pathname.

And

> On windows realpath() will change unix style paths to windows style.

Answer (score 1):

It replaces (consecutive) occurences of / and \ with
whatever is in DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, and processes /. and /.. fine.
Paths returned by get_absolute_path() contain no
(back)slash at position 0 (beginning of the string) or
position -1 (ending)

```
function get_absolute_path($path) {
    $path = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
    $parts = array_filter(explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path), 'strlen');
    $absolutes = array();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if ('.' == $part) continue;
        if ('..' == $part) {
            array_pop($absolutes);
        } else {
            $absolutes[] = $part;
        }
    }
    return implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $absolutes);
}
```

A test:

```
var_dump(get_absolute_path('this/is/../a/./test/.///is'));
```

Returns: string(14) `"this/a/test/is"`

Answer (score 0):

`while(strlen($path) != (strlen($path = str_replace('//','/', $path))));`

This code replaces double slashes with single slash, as long as it changes length;