# PHP - Get URL and remove the trailing slash

Tags: php

So I've created this function that get's the URL of the Website, but I also want it to remove the trailing `/` as well.

So far I have this:

```
function base_url() {
    $base_url = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';

    return $base_url.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

But I don't know how to remove the trailing `/` from the URL.

I've also tried to add the `rtrim` but still no luck:

```
function base_url() {
    $base_url = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    $base_url = rtrim($base_url, '/');

    return $base_url.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Image of the URL -

[image]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php (`rtrim( $url, '/' )`.

Comment: I've already tried this and still no luck with it :/

Comment: Can you show how you tried that, and what the url looked like after the `rtrim`?

Comment: Why add an image? Just paste the URL into the question and surround it with backticks (`\``). Blanking out a section of it just makes it harder to find the issue...

Comment: 'https' and 'http' will never have a trailing slash.   you're applying rtrim() in the wrong place

Comment: take it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494515/remove-unnecessary-slashes-from-path

Comment: @DJDavid98 I've added the URL, also @Brad Kent well something is adding the trailing `/` as you can see from the URL there is an extra one their

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function base_url() {
    $base_url = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' ? 'https' : 'http';
    $base_url.= '://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    return rtrim( $base_url, '/' );
}
```