# PHP Post value without adding slashes

Tags: php

I have this PHP code that contacts an external API

```
$arr = array(
        "domain_name" => $_POST["domain"],
       "auto_renew" => false,
       "domain_lock" => false,
       "whois_privacy" => false, 
       "contact_registrant_id" => $_POST["registrant_contact"], 
       "contact_admin_id" => $_POST["admin_contact"], 
       "contact_tech_id" => $_POST["tech_contact"], 
       "contact_billing_id" => $_POST["billing_contact"], 
       "auth_code" =>($_POST["auth_code"])
    );
```

The value I am posting for `$_POST["auth_code"]` is `l&"IkM%Wbjjq7`

However, when it posts this value, its being posted as `l&\\\"IkM%Wbjjq7`

So its adding the slashes, which is causing a problem.

Comment: have you tried addslashes()?

Comment: why would i `addslashes` when i dont want them

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339145/how-to-remove-multiple-slashes-in-uri-with-preg-or-htaccess

Comment: even you can you can use stripslashes(). http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_stripslashes.asp

Answer (score 1):

it may help you. The "magic_quotes_gpc" might be on.You can disable it in php.ini.

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off 

OR 

$str = $_POST["auth_code"];
echo get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($str) : $str;

OR 

echo stripslashes($str);
```

Comment: this is currently disabled

Answer (score 0):

This is *probably* due to magic quotes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/517027/4275413 and http://php.net/manual/de/security.magicquotes.disabling.php for further details (second link official way to "disable" them).

This once was a good idea to protect the user (read the coder) from himself, when inserting stuff into the database or some other place, by adding escaping by default, which of course ruins almost every script not expecting it.